# How to stop autostart a video at 2 sec in html using embed object

Tags: php, html, embed

i am having a problem.

I am having a script which is embeding a video from database.

The issue is that i can make autostart false to stop the video from playing automaticaly

the issue is that i want to make autostart false in such a way that the video will be stopped at the frame of 2 secs of play.

here's my code

```
    <object id="MediaPlayer" classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" width="205" height="180" standby="Loading Windows Media Player components…" type="application/x-oleobject" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">
<param name="FileName" value="<?php echo base_url().$cl['post_file'];?>">
<param name="AutoStart" value="false">
<param name="ShowControls" value="true">
<param name="BufferingTime" value="2">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
<param name="AutoSize" value="true">
<param name="InvokeURLs" value="false">
<param name="AnimationatStart" value="1">
<param name="TransparentatStart" value="1">
<param name="Loop" value="0">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2'" src="<?php echo base_url().$cl['post_file'];?>" name="MediaPlayer" autostart="0" showstatusbar="1" showdisplay="1" showcontrols="1" loop="0" videoborder3d="0" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" width="205" height="180"
                                                                stretchToFit="true"></embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I am trying to understand your goal.

So if the video is buffering you want it to start at 2 seconds in?

I am NOT an IE expert but this should get you on the right track at least.

```
 document.getElementById('MediaPlayer').attachEvent("PlayStateChange",function(newState) {
        if(newState == "Buffering")
        {
             document.getElementById('MediaPlayer').currentPosition = 2;
        }
    });
```